# Can not read property 'msg' of undifined

Tags: reactjs

```
 const onSubmit = async () => {
    showError(false)
    try{
      await axios.post("http://localhost:9005/api/Users", user);
      // history.push("/")
      handleClose()
      props.snackbarShowMessage(`User Added Successfully `)
      data()
      formReset()
    }catch(error){
      showError(true)
      console.log('asdfg',error)
      props.snackbarShowError(error.response.data.error[0].msg)
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Assign response to variable , then check its response status.
you can verify this by using...

```
const x =  await axios.post("http://localhost:9005/api/Users", user);

console.log(x.statusCode);
```

Note that try catch will handle react error not axios error..